# Optimization with non-box bounds in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, data-fitting

I am using [optim()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html) with the `Nelder-Mead` and `BFGS` to fit a rather
complicated function with 4 parameter

```
initial <- c(dep=2, z0=2, na=6, zjoint=5)
```

The function to be minimised is the sum of squares of the function and
an observed wind profile (functions can be seen below). I do this
individually for about 2000 wind profiles, so I end up with a
distribution for each parameter.

The function (`wpLELDefault`) has box bounds for the parameter,

```
0 <= dep, z0, na, zjoint
28 >= dep, z0, zjoint
```

but also the condition that

```
dep + z0 < 28
```

now the function `wpLELDefault()` is implemented in such a way, that it
returns NA if the parameter are out of the allowed range.

If I use `Nelder-Mead` the parameter distribution is very sensitive to the initial values for `optim()` and in a majority of cases
ending at the extreme sides or having a rough distribution with many spikes.

`BFGS` works much better (smoother parameter value distribution), but does seem to have often problems with the NA values, consequently not being able to fit many wind profiles.

Using `L-BFGS-B` with bounds poses the problem on how to specify the
non-box condition for `dep+z0`.

So my question:

- What is the best way to approach this problem?
- Are there more robust optimization routines to NA values returned by the function?
- Which ones in `R` allow to specify non-box bounds? I would prefer a function which deals gracefully with returned NAs as I also want to fit another function with more complex bounds.

I looked at the [CRAN Task View Optimization and Mathematical Programming](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), but I could not find anything (I must admit, my knowledge at the issue of optimization is rather limited).

The function `wpLELDefault`

```
wpLELDefault <- function(
    z,
    ua,
    dep,
    z0,
    na, #    = 7,
    zjoint,
    h,  #    = 28,
    za, #    = 37,
    z0sol,# = 0.001,
    noU   = FALSE,
    check = TRUE
    ){ 
    vk <- 0.41

    ok <- ifelse(
        check,
        parameterOK(
            z      = z,
            ua     = ua,
            dep    = dep,
            z0     = z0,
            na     = na,
            zjoint = zjoint,
            h      = h,
            za     = za,
            z0sol  = z0sol
            ),
        TRUE
        )

    if (!isTRUE(ok)) {
        stop(ok)
    }

    ustar    <- ua * vk / log( (za - dep) / z0)

    z0h   <- z0 * exp( -6.27 * vk * ( ustar^(1/3) ) )

    uzjoint  <- (ustar /  vk) * log( (h       - dep)/z0 ) * exp( - na * (1 - zjoint/h      ) )

    ustarsol <- ifelse(
        (zjoint == 0),
        as.numeric(NA),
        uzjoint * vk / log( zjoint / z0sol )
        )

    ##
    result <- list(
        z = NA,
        u = NA,
        u.onlyTop = NA
        )

    if (!noU) {
        result$z <- as.numeric(z)
        ##
        result$u <- as.numeric(
            sapply(
                z,
                function(z) {
                    if (z >= h) {

                        u <-  ( ustar/vk ) * log( (z-dep) / z0 )
                    } else if (z >= zjoint) {

                          uh <- ( ustar/vk ) * log( (h-dep) / z0 )
                          u <- uh * exp( -na*(1-(z/h)) )
                      } else if (z >= 0) {

                            u <- ( ustarsol/vk ) * log( (z     ) / z0sol )
                        } else {
                              u <- NA
                          }
                    return(u)
                }
                )
            )
        names(result$u) <- paste0("h", z)
        ##
        result$u.onlyTop = as.numeric(
            sapply(
                z,
                function(z) {
                    zd <- ((z-dep) / z0)
                    if (zd < 0){
                        u <- NA
                    } else {
                          u <- ( ustar/vk ) * log( (z-dep) / z0 )
                      }
                    if (!is.na(u)) {
                        if (u < 0) {
                            u <- NA
                        }
                    }
                    return(u)
                }
                )
            )
    }
    ##
    result$parametrization <- "default"
    result$dep       <- as.numeric(dep)
    result$z0        <- as.numeric(z0)
    result$na        <- as.numeric(na)
    result$zjoint    <- as.numeric(zjoint)
    result$h         <- as.numeric(h)
    result$za        <- as.numeric(za)
    result$z0sol     <- as.numeric(z0sol)

    result$vk        <- as.numeric(vk)
    result$ua        <- as.numeric(ua)
    result$ustar     <- as.numeric(ustar)
    result$z0h       <- as.numeric(z0h)
    result$uzjoint   <- as.numeric(uzjoint)
    result$ustarsol  <- as.numeric(ustarsol)
    ##
    result$noU       <- noU
    result$check     <- check
    ##
    class(result) <- c("wpLEL")
    return(result)
}
```

The function `fitOptim.wpLEL.default.single`

```
fitOptim.wpLEL.default.single <- function(
    z,
    u,
    LAI,
    initial = c(dep=25, z0=0.8*28,  na=9, zjoint=0.2*2),
    h      = 28,
    za     = 37,
    z0sol  = 0.001,
    ...
    ) {
    ## Function to be minimised
    wpLELMin <- function(par, z, u, ua, h, za, z0sol) {
        if (
            isTRUE(
                parameterOK(
                    z      = z,
                    ua     = ua,
                    dep    = par[1], # par$dep,
                    z0     = par[2], # par$z0,
                    na     = par[3], # par$na,
                    zjoint = par[4], # par$zjoint
                    h      = h,
                    za     = za,
                    z0sol  = z0sol
                    )
                )
            ) {
            p <- wpLELDefault(
                z      = z,
                ua     = ua,
                dep    = par[1], # par$dep,
                z0     = par[2], # par$z0,
                na     = par[3], # par$na,
                zjoint = par[4], # par$zjoint
                h      = h,
                za     = za,
                z0sol  = z0sol,
                check = FALSE
                )
            result <- sum( ( (p$u - u)^2 ) / length(u) )
        } else {
              result <- NA
          }
        return( result )
    } 

    ua <- u[length(u)]
    result <- list()
    result$method <- "fitOptim.wpLEL.default.single"
    result$initial <-  initial
    result$dot <- list(...)
    result$z <- z
    result$u <- u
    result$fit <- optim(
        par = c(
            initial["dep"],
            initial["z0"],
            initial["na"],
            initial["zjoint"]
            ),
        fn    = wpLELMin,
        z     = z,
        u     = u,
        ua    = ua,
        h     = h,
        za    = za,
        z0sol = z0sol,
        ...
        )
    result$wp <- wpLELDefault(
        z      = z,
        ua     = ua,
        dep    = result$fit$par["dep"],
        z0     = result$fit$par["z0"],
        na     = result$fit$par["na"],
        zjoint = result$fit$par["zjoint"],
        h      = h,
        za     = za,
        z0sol  = z0sol
        )

    class(result) <- c(class(result), "wpLELFit")
    return(result)
}
```

Comment: have you looked at `?constrOptim` yet?  It handles linear inequality constraints, which is what you're looking for ... (It would also be good to give a reproducible example ...)

Comment: Thanks - ```constrOptim()``` works nicely for the linear constraints. I'll start a new question concerning non-linear constraints. Unfortunately, I can no accept a comment as answer.

Comment: @BenBolker Here is the follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845169/how-to-optimize-with-non-linear-constraints-in-r